# Get the application to login screen, MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have made an application which has login screen. When the user logs in with authorized password, he lands on the working screen.

Now what I would like to do is automatic log off when the user is not active for specific amount of time.

What I first thought is I should close the application then relaunch the application that will take the user to the login screen, but if I close the application then I want be able to relaunch the application. So what probably can solve my requirement here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*To track inactivity:*

Use a hook for the current application for mouse and keyboard.
Here **was** a sample code. But the technique is still OK.

http://web.archive.org/web/20020306115840/http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/dnmsj00/html/cpp0200.asp

sadly the sample code is gone because they deleted all old MSDN articles.

*To logon again:*

When you track inactivity you can simply launch your application again with ShellExecute and quit.

Comment: I din't get the logon again part, Can you please explain in details.

Comment: Just launch you application again with ShellExecute and destroy your main window. This will terminate your old (timed out) application and launch a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a lock/unlock dialog without using login function again, you can hide the main window while lock it, and show the window after unlock.

And for check user active, you should check mouse move/keyboard input event in a period of time.

Comment: But after timeout i have to show the login screen to user. How can that be done. Right now I am closing my application using `exit(1)`. If possible how can i restart the application after it exits from the same program.